# Reading encrypted data from Snowflake

Tags: c#, .net-core, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a c# application created from snowflake example https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-to-connect-to-snowflake-using-C-Sharp-application-with-snowflake-NET-Connector-to-perform-SQL-operations-in-windows

I can connect to Snowflake just fine (using externalbrowser type for azure AD auth), but when I get the result from the SELECT SQL the data looks like this:

78bcbded-6961-52gc-a427-bfdb7ce62854 (one row apparently)

I assume that is some sort of encryption, but I have no idea how to figure out what kind so that I could find out how to decrypt it.

If I run queries in the Snowflake UI the data looks fine, the above happens when I run queries via c# app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the column contains GUID/UUID. It is not an encryption.

More: [Universally unique identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier)

As we do not see the code, I guess it is not the actual resultset, but rather Query Id.

Comment: Well that was embarissingly simple. So yes, the problem was in the reault handling, I was getting only the ID filed, which was indeed a GUID, instead of the fields I needed. Thanks!